# Using contain In where statement in Entity Framework make performance too low

Tags: c#

I have three tables in database :

```
Customer, SalesManTabels, CustomerSalesManTabels
```

Now I use this code in Entity Framework and C# to get all customer from the `Customer` table
except customers that are contained in the `CustomerSalesmansTabel` for the same salesman:

```
 List<CustomerSalesManTabel> CustomerSalesManList = new List<CustomerSalesManTabel>();
    List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();
    MedicalCustomersDBEntities PuplicEntityForSave = new MedicalCustomersDBEntities();
     private void LoadCustomerSalesManToList()
     {  
      IEnumerable<CustomerSalesManTabel> Cus = from a in PuplicEntityForSave.CustomerSalesManTabels.Include("SalesManTabel") select a;
      CustomerSalesManList.AddRange(Cus);  
     }

     private void LoadCustomerToList()
     {
      MedicalCustomersDBEntities md = new MedicalCustomersDBEntities();
      IEnumerable<Customer> Cus = from a in md.Customers select a;
      CustomerList.AddRange(Cus);
      }

    IEnumerable<Guid?> CustomerSalesManIEnumerable = CustomerSalesManList.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.SalesManId == SalesManId).Select(s => s.CustomerId);

     var Cus = from nb in CustomerList
      where CustomerSalesManIEnumerable.Contains(nb.Id) == false
      select nb;

    checkedListBoxControlNonSelected.ValueMember = "Id";
    checkedListBoxControlNonSelected.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
    checkedListBoxControlNonSelected.DataSource = Cus.ToList<Customer>();
```

This code works, but my problem with `Contains` because I have a huge data, I have 12000 `Customer` when I use `Contains` it takes too long when I assigned "cus" to DataSourceof checklistbox

I want another way to do code like this but with high performance ?

Comment: There is never a reason to write `from a in x select a`.

Comment: You are completely misusing EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you are looping through a lot more than you need, because you are not realising the result in `CustomerSalesManIEnumerable`, so each time you use `Contains` it looks in the entire result from CustomerSalesManList (which is realised by `AsEnumerable`).

Realising the result as a list gives you less data to wade through. As you want to look for items in the result, you want a collection which uses a hash so that you get a fast lookup, like a `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<Guid?> CustomerSalesManIEnumerable = new HashSet(CustomerSalesManList.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.SalesManId == SalesManId).Select(s => s.CustomerId));
```

You should however consider if this is possible to do in the database instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're downloading all of the lists to the client, then filtering them in-memory.
This defeats the purpose of the Entity Framework.

You should run your queries directly against your DataContext:

```
from c in entities.Customers
where !entites.CustomerSalesManTabels.Any(s => c.Id == s.CustomerId)
select c
```

Comment: +1 - exactly - presenting 12'000 customers on the UI for the user to pick from - insane....

Comment: dear I use select join but the program is too slowly when I use the contains with select join                                             what can I do please

Comment: IEnumerable<Guid?> CustomerSalesManIEnumerable = CustomerSalesManList.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.SalesManId == SalesManId).Select(s => s.CustomerId);

                var Cus = from nb in CustomerList
                          where CustomerSalesManIEnumerable.Contains(nb.Id) == false
                          select nb;

Comment: As I've been trying to tell you, **that is completely wrong.  You need to run on the server** by querying the DataContext directly.